# Spring Specification Criteria Multiple Joins ? How?

Tags: spring, join, criteria, specifications

I got stuck using a Spring Project with Spring Data + specification + criteria api.

I will try to simulate the situation with general entities we used write to get easy example.

**The Entities:** 
Consider all attributes of the each entity is passed on the constructor showed below

**Country**(Long id, String name, String iso)
**State**(Long id, String name, String iso)
**City**(Long id, String name, String iso)

This is my repository:

```
public interface CityRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<City, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<City> {

}
```

As you can see, I don't need to implement anything on the repository

This is my service

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class CityService {

    @Autowired
    private CityRepository cityRepository;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public CityListVO findByNameLike(String name, PageRequest pageRequest) {
        name = "%" + name + "%";

        if (pageRequest == null) {
            List<City> result = cityRepository.findAll(fillGridCriteria(name));
            return new CityListVO(1, result.size(), result);
        } else {
            Page<City> result = cityRepository. findAll(fillGridCriteria(name), pageRequest);
            return new CityListVO(result.getTotalPages(), result.getTotalElements(), result.getContent());
        }

    }

    private static Specification<City> fillGridCriteria(String name) {
        return new Specification<City>() {

            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(
                    Root<City> root,
                    CriteriaQuery<?> query,
                    CriteriaBuilder builder) { 

             /*
                The current return I can do a like by name, and it works fine. 

                My problem is if for any reason I need to do multiple joins like the folow jpql: 
                select ci FROM City ci, State st, Country co where ci.st = st AND st.co = co AND co.name = 'Canada';

                How to do this from here ? Inside this method.
                How is gonna be the return for this method ?

             */

                return builder.like(root.get("name"), name.trim());
            }

        };
    }

}
```

Comment: is there a relation between entities ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you want all the cities that their country's name like `name` and you have a relational Model in which :

```
Country(Long id, String name, String iso)
State(Long id,Long country, String name, String iso)
City(Long id, Long state, String name, String iso)
```

**Predicate:**

```
private static Specification<City> fillGridCriteria(String name) {
    return new Specification<City>() {

        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(
                Root<City> root,
                CriteriaQuery<?> query,
                CriteriaBuilder builder) { 

          return 
            builder.like(root.get("state").get("country").get("name"), name.trim());
        }

    };
}
```

Comment: @GlauterLemos in case you want join in `@ManyToMany` or `@OneToMany` you can use `root.join` ,specifications is very verbose, if i were you i wiill use querydsl it is much simpler and less verbose, :)

Comment: I agree  Rafik, I just worry about this http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/reference/html/core.querydsl.html